# add a preventing method where user cannot create a existing account with name and email

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

### I would like to implement a method which would prevent the user to create an exisiting account where the name and email have already been used

```
 try{
        String query="Insert into users(name,email,password)values(?,?,?)";
       pst=conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pst.setString(1,nam.getText());
        pst.setString(2,emal.getText());
        pst.setString(3,pass.getText());
        int affectedrows=pst.executeUpdate();
        rs=pst.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt(1);
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your account has been registerd");
            dispose();
            new Landing_Page(id);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account already exists");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e ){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());    
    }
}
```

Comment: best way to prevent that is to add a unique key to the column(s) in MySQL's table.

Comment: they do have an unique id if thats what you are suggesting but i want a coding method that would display the user that if the name and email inputed already exist it would not let them create the accout

Comment: Like @ Raymond Nijland in database, use unique constrain. In  Java, create a method that find in the couple (name,email) exist in database or not and use it before insertion

Comment: you can create table with composite primary key (name,email)

Comment: After you create the constraints in DB, in case when the username/email is already used you'll receive the specified exception. So in the code you can check the error code and display a message to a user

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to **select** query both email and name from the database and **if** the resultSet of the queries were empty then insert into the table.

imagine you have a table in your database as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

now the code below first selects from the database the name and email that were set as the argument in this method and then if the values where empty(checks it with resultSet method next()) starts inserting into the table:

```
 public static void insertUser(String name,String email,String pass)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String queryName = "select * from users where name = ?";
    String queryEmail = "select * from users where email = ?";
    boolean nameExists = false; 
    boolean emailExists = false;
    try
    {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflow", "root", "red devils11");
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryName);
        ps.setString(1, name);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        nameExists =  rs.next();

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryEmail);
        ps.setString(1, email);
        rs.close();
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        emailExists = rs.next();
        if(!nameExists && !emailExists)
        {
            String insertUser = "insert into users(name,email,password) values(?,?,?)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertUser);
            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, email);
            ps.setString(3, pass);
            ps.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("user or email is already in the database");
        }


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            rs.close();
            ps.cancel();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}//insertUser
```

> remember to add jconnector for mysql to the jre library of your
>   project or you won't even get connected https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: if you may can you show me how to do it in code because i am looking at many examples on the internet but i can not find a correct solution for my code above

Comment: i understand the theory but i cant seem to do it :(

Comment: im sorry if it took too long for me to see your message. anyhow i added the answer you needed to the edit iv done above. ill appreciate it if you check this post as the answer(the check mark on the left side of my answer) and rate it up. thank you